# Not able to recognize persistence unit using Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa

> [2/13/20 20:39:52:987 CST] 000000a5 AbstractJPACo W   CWWJP0010W: The
>   server cannot locate the deployed application, which is called GREEar,
>   when it attempts to find the FatcaIntegration persistence unit in the
>   GREEjb.jar module. [2/13/20 20:39:52:993 CST] 000000a5 InjectionBind E
>   CWNEN0035E: The
>   java:comp/env/com.ramana.fatca.service.GFUClassificationService/entityManager
>   reference of type javax.persistence.EntityManager for the
>   GFUClassificationService component in the GREEjb.jar module of the
>   GREEar application cannot be resolved. [2/13/20 20:39:52:996 CST]
>   000000a5 BusinessExcep E   CNTR0019E: EJB threw an unexpected
>   (non-declared) exception during invocation of method
>   "classifyAccount". Exception data: javax.ejb.EJBException: The
>   java:comp/env/com.ramana.fatca.service.GFUClassificationService/entityManager
>   reference of type javax.persistence.EntityManager for the
>   GFUClassificationService component in the GREEjb.jar module of the
>   GREEar application cannot be resolved.    at
>   com.ibm.wsspi.injectionengine.InjectionBinding.getInjectionObject(InjectionBinding.java:1493)
>     at
>   com.ibm.wsspi.injectionengine.InjectionBinding.getInjectableObject(InjectionBinding.java:1373)
>     at
>   com.ibm.wsspi.injectionengine.InjectionTarget.inject(InjectionTarget.java:108)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.injectionengine.AbstractInjectionEngine.inject(AbstractInjectionEngine.java:852)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ejs.container.ManagedBeanOBase.injectInstance(ManagedBeanOBase.java:148)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ejs.container.StatelessBeanO.injectInstance(StatelessBeanO.java:295)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ejs.container.StatelessBeanO.initialize(StatelessBeanO.java:169)
>     at com.ibm.ejs.container.BeanOFactory.create(BeanOFactory.java:105)
>     at com.ibm.ejs.container.EJSHome.createBeanO(EJSHome.java:976)  at
>   com.ibm.ejs.container.EJSHome.createBeanO(EJSHome.java:1078)  at
>   com.ibm.ejs.container.activator.UncachedActivationStrategy.atActivate(UncachedActivationStrategy.java:63)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ejs.container.activator.Activator.preInvokeActivateBean(Activator.java:264)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ejs.container.EJSContainer.preInvokeActivate(EJSContainer.java:3242)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ejs.container.EJSContainer.EjbPreInvoke(EJSContainer.java:2579)
>     at
>   com.ramana.fatca.service.EJSRemote0SLGFUClassificationService_948cbf78.classifyAccount(EJSRemote0SLGFUClassificationService_948cbf78.java)    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:90)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:508)     at
>   com.ibm.CORBA.iiop.ClientDelegate$5.run(ClientDelegate.java:1319)     at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:770)
>     at
>   com.ibm.CORBA.iiop.ClientDelegate.invoke0(ClientDelegate.java:1317)
>     at
>   com.ibm.CORBA.iiop.ClientDelegate$ClientDelegate0.invoke(ClientDelegate.java:1553)
>     at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy241.classifyAccount(Unknown Source)  at
>   com.ramana.fatca.service._GFUClassificationServiceRemote_Stub.classifyAccount(_GFUClassificationServiceRemote_Stub.java:1)
>     at
>   com.ramana.fatca.service.GFUAdaptor.getClassification(GFUAdaptor.java:102)
>     at
>   com.ramana.fatca.service.GFUAdaptor$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$9bb914c5.invoke()
>     at
>   org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:736)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
>     at
>   org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
>     at
>   org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282)
>     at
>   org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:671)
>     at
>   com.ramana.fatca.service.GFUAdaptor$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$5aa7bb73.getClassification()
>     at
>   com.ramana.fatca.service.USIndiciaCheckIndividualService.submitIndiciaIndividual(USIndiciaCheckIndividualService.java:576)
>     at
>   com.ramana.fatca.service.USIndiciaCheckIndividualService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$e1c5e71.invoke()
>     at
>   org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:736)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
>     at
>   org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
>     at
>   org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282)
>     at
>   org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:671)
>     at
>   com.ramana.fatca.service.USIndiciaCheckIndividualService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$4e2703f7.submitIndiciaIndividual()
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:90)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:508)     at
>   com.ramana.common.delegate.BaseDelegate.callService(BaseDelegate.java:172)
>     at
>   com.ramana.common.delegate.BaseDelegate.callService(BaseDelegate.java:184)
>     at
>   com.ramana.common.delegate.DataDelegate.processEntity(DataDelegate.java:201)
>     at
>   com.ramana.common.controller.DataController.processDelegate(DataController.java:283)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:90)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:508)     at
>   org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:97)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:849)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:760)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1235)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:779)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:478)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:179)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:143)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:96)
>     at com.ramana.common.filter.DataFilter.doFilter(DataFilter.java:40)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:197)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:90)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:969)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1109)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:82)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:963)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1817)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:382)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:465)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:532)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:318)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:88)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
>     at
>   com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
>     at
>   com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
>     at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)     at
>   com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)   at
>   com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
>     at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)     at
>   com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1909)

Comment: Fixed style of the question, with stacktrace

Answer (score 0):

Issue has been resolved, it is throwing due to the incompatibility of the jars between WAS provided(built in/comes along with WAS) and the jars which i added to shared lib